# Getting "Multiple roles associated to instance" error while trying to associate new IAM role to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I checked on this post for solutions: [EC2 Instance error telling me multiple IAM Roles are attached when I try to change it...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851005/ec2-instance-error-telling-me-multiple-iam-roles-are-attached-when-i-try-to-chan)

`>aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations --filters Name=instance-id,Values=i-xxxxxxx { "IamInstanceProfileAssociations": [] }`

However it is not working for me.
I am seeing that when I try to describe the instance profile for the instance for which I am seeing issue, I don't see any association ID info. However when trying to change IAM role on AWS console, I see the above error. Could anyone please help me out here?

[image]

According to the other post it suggests that an empty response for the describe instance profile means that no role is associated.

So I attempted a new role association via CLI which is failing because of:

```
aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id i-xxxx --iam-instance-profile Name=xxxx
```

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AssociateIamInstanceProfile operation: Value (xxx) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name`

I tried with ARN also and it gave me the same error. It is a valid IAM role that I just created which has `ec2.amazon.aws` specified in the Principal under the service key. Why is this happening?